# Can we know how many vectors we need to enlarge a linearly independent set to a basis WITHOUT first having proved Replacement Theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, namely $V$ has a finite basis. Let $S\subseteq V$. If at this time, we have not proved Replacement Theorem, and hence we don't know the relative size between an arbitrary linearly independent set and an arbitrary spanning set of $V$.

Now, If $S$ is linearly independent and $S$ doesn't span $V$. We want to enlarge $S$ to a basis. We know that we can take any $v\notin \text{span}(S)$, and add it to $S$, then $S\cup \{v\}$ must be linearly independent, while $\text{span}(S)\subsetneq\text{span}(S\cup\{v\})$. In other words, the span will be enlarged. Logically, keep adding vector which is not belongs to current span, then the resulting set will span a strictly larger subspace; and at the same time keeping the linearly indenpendency. However, if $\dim V=n$, can we know that the numbers of vectors we should add is exactly $n-|S|$ without having proved the Replacement Theorem first?

Comment: I'm not sure what the Replacement Theorem is exactly, but it sounds to me like you have a chicken-and-egg situation here: you've specified the dimension of V but you haven't even proven that all bases have the same cardinality.

Comment: I see! You're right. This is where the problem arise! In fact, I ask this because one of my book(not textbook really, a kind of handout) said this before introducing the Replacement theorem.

Comment: Yeah, the exact order of the results can vary a bit, but at the end of the day, "all bases have the same cardinality, which we call the dimension d", "all spanning sets contain at least d elements", "all linearly independent sets contain at most d elements". One way or the other you have to prove these, and I'm pretty sure at least one of them will require you to "get into the weeds" rather than working at a higher level.